# xmlrpc in viewbased application

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, xml-rpc, iphone

Greetings,

I am working on a xmlrpc viewbased iphone application . i am facing with the framework issue . 
I would like to know which are the frameworks used in this process and also the headers that would be needed . i have tried adding the 
import but on build i get errors which say

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/WebServicesCore.framework/Headers/WSMethodInvocation.h:759:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/WebServicesCore.framework/Headers/WSMethodInvocation.h:759: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'CFXMLTreeRef'

i appreciate any help given to me .

Thank you

Comment: If my answer was useful to you..you may consider a up-vote to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the the following frameworks
    WebServicesCore.framework
    CoreServices.framework
Import the folllowing headers.. 
    WSMethodInvocation.h
    WSProtocolHandler.h
    WSTypes.h

Then you are good to go